# How to make a toggle initially loaded as hidden without JS recognize it as invisible?

Tags: javascript, toggle

Ideally, I want to have 2 toggler. When click the fieldset toggler, the fieldset shows up with a div inside being hidden. When an event happened or When click the div toggler, the div show up. 
**I can only manage one of the 2 toggler working.**

This is the html

```
<a href="#" class="fieldset-toogler-trigger">click here</a>
<fieldset class="fieldset" style="display:none">
<input>//first inputs
<input> 2nd input
<input id="edit-text" name="custom-text" type="checkbox value=""/>
<div id="wrapper">include several fields that initially hidden</div>
</fieldset>
```

This is the toggler for the fieldset:

```
$("a.fieldset-toggle-trigger").click(function() {
  $(".fieldset").toggle();
}
```

The div toggler is inside another groups of code:

```
var e_fields = $("div#wrapper");
    //fadein/fadeout with an event:
    function bindEditTextClick(){
      $("input#edit-text").click( function() {
      if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        e_fields.fadeIn(750);
      } else {
        e_fields.fadeOut(750, function() {
      });
    }
    });
    }

    //toggle as a part of another live click fuunction:
    if (e_fields.is(':visible')) {
        e_fields.fadeOut(500);
    }
```

**If I let the fieldset initially loaded as visible, the inside toggle works fine.** This inside toggle is connected to other events, not easy to modify.  How can I modify the fieldset toggler to allow inside toggle continue working?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correct you want to toggle main section and then toggle inner section depends on checkbox state. Is so, code and working solutions are below:

**html**

```
<a href="#" class="fieldset-toogler-trigger">click here</a>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <input /><br />
    <input /><br />
    <input id="edit-text" name="custom-text" type="checkbox" value=""/>
    <div id="wrapper">include several fields that initially hidden</div>
</fieldset>
```

**css**

```
fieldset { display:none; }
#wrapper { display:none; }
```

**js**

```
$(function() {
    $(".fieldset-toogler-trigger").click(function() {
        $(".fieldset").toggle();
    });
    $("#edit-text").change(function() {
        var action = 'fadeOut';
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            action = 'fadeIn';
        }
        $('#wrapper')[action](750);
    });
});
```

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/y7PKk/

Comment: Your code works when used in a standalone situation. but doesn't work in my case. seems the visibility of fieldset effects on the inside toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for toggle the entire fieldset without messing up the inside toggle:
Initially move away the fieldset instead of hide the fieldset:

```
.moveaway{
    position:absolute;left:-999em;
}
```

Then, use the fieldset toggler to toggle the moveaway class on/off.